# How to resize the width of a div based on another div on it's right, only with CSS(no JS)

Tags: html, css, resize

I need two divs aligned horizontally to have the following behavior:

When the div on the right changes size, it should change the width of the div on the left, either by making it smaller or making it bigger.

Also the solution needs to be purely html & css, no javascript whatsoever.
I added a picture as an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuaFK.png

Comment: First of all, what @LcSalazar said. Secondly, how will you change the width of the div?

Comment: I suggest you start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: use `calc`, besides that i'm not coding for you.

Comment: I shall change it's DIV2's width by adding more horizontal content to it.

Comment: You have to understand this is not an 'i need this code for me' question, I've been trying to wrap my head around this all day and it's just not possible to do with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I believe putting the two divs into a wrapper, and then assign each div inside of the wrapper a certain width by % may help. This will not change the aspect of your width, in your image example you could not go from the second image to the third image by simply adding more content to the div. However you could get those different setups easily, and if you want the width of each div to change based on screen size you can use media queries for that.

So an example of code using a wrapper,

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="one">
        Some content for the first div
   </div>
   <div class="two">
        Some content for the second div
   </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  max-width:1000px;
}
.one{
  float:left;
  width:40%;
}
.two{
  float:left;
  width:60%
}
```

Using this code should give you two divs, the first would be 40% of the wrapper, or a max of 400px wide, the second div would be 60% of the wrapper, or a max of 600px wide.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible without javascript but u can  try this code....

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;
}
#first
{
height:120px;
border:solid blue 1px;
float:left;
min-width:8%;
width:38%;
margin-left:2%;
}
#second
{
height:120px;
border:solid pink 1px;
float:left;
width:58%;
max-width:88%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div id="first" >
Div 1
</div>
<div id="second">
Div 2
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to manage this without an event to trigger it.

CSS does support on hover and other events that you can use to change the appearance of divs.

Short of this you may want to use CSS LESS which supports conditionals